# Size of a div that contains an image and 2 other divs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My HTML:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="header-img">
      <img src="test_bg.jpg" class="bg" />
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-1 logo"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-3 logo"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
$test-color : red;

.header-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;

}

.logo {
  background-color: $test-color;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

What i want:

The header div has the size of the image it contains and the two other divs are on the image at the top of it.

The problem is, if I make the img absolute the two divs are on top but the header div hasn't the size of the image.

Is it possible to have both?

Comment: If you set the dimensions of the images manually, yes.

Comment: i want it to be resizable, there's no other solutions ?

Comment: If this image is basically a background image (as you called it in your class name), why not use it in the CSS as a `background-image`? This will give you precisely what you want...

Comment: `width: 100%`? I'm not sure of what exactly you're trying to do with it.

Comment: so u want the 2 divs to show completely? i still fail to understand

Comment: `if I make the img absolute` why do you need that the image will be absolute?

Comment: because i want the two divs placed on the image at the top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just wrap the red divs with container with `position:absolute`?

Like this?

```css
.header-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;

}

.s {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
}

.logo {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="header-img">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MqG7.jpg" class="bg" />
      <div class="s">
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-1 logo"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-3 logo"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using good approach, the case like this we don't use image throug image tag. You should use background image like

```
.header-img{
background-image: url("test_bg.jpg");
height: 700px; /*put height of your image here*/
background-size: cover; 
}
```

Now you not need to apply position absolute to your both of divs.
Put above style in your css and make sure path of your image is correct

Hope it would be helpful
Thanks

Comment: i tried this but i want my div to have the size of the image... in your case it will be always 700px i want it to be automatic

Answer (score 0):

You should prepare a jsfiddle, but make .header-img position:relative and then set the bottom or top properties of .logo to what you want.

```
.header-img { position: relative;}
.logo { bottom: 0px;}
```

The issue is you'll need to set left or right for the .logo divs because they'll render on top of each other.(you can set for example  left: 15px for the left one and right:15px to the right one)

https://jsfiddle.net/ivankovachev/wodpdrzq/

Answer (score 0):

You can `position` your parent header element to `relative` and `position` your image to `absolute` so the red div's come over the image.

```
.header{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.bg{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;

}

.logo{
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

See a working fiddle here: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4635vu5v/)

Comment: Ok but i also want my div to have the size of the image it contains

Comment: You mean height? Because now you use the bootstrap `col-*` so the width is limited to the percentage of that.